# Import csv to postgresql: Missing data for the column

Tags: postgresql, csv

I try to import data from csv to my database postgresql, i use COPY but i have this error message:

> ERROR:  Missing data for the column « inventaire »

this is my instruction:

```
COPY calcul FROM 'C:/vente.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

Comment: **Edit** your question and add the `create table` statement for your table and some sample lines from your input file.

Answer (score 0):

Do not get it wrong because

`COPY` is used for [SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)

while

`\copy` is used for [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

i.e

```
\copy calcul FROM 'C:/vente.csv' (FORMAT csv, HEADER, DELIMITER ',');
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: If khadi8 couldn't use `copy` Postgres would give a different error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this should work for him, except he is not calling the right path for the `.csv` file.

Comment: postgresql doesn't renognize \copy i get this error 
ERREUR:  syntaxe error near « \ »
LINE 1: \copy calcul FROM 'C:/vente.csv' (FORMAT csv, HEADER, DELIMI...
        ^